# View PHP code after includes

Tags: php

Basically, I need to view the PHP code of a file, after includes. I am trying to see EXACTLY what PHP code is run. eg...

```
<?php // a.php
    $a = 10;
?>

<?php // b.php
    include('a.php');
    $b = 20;
?>
```

If I was trying to get the code of b.php, it would display the following:

```
<?php
    $a = 10;
    $b = 20;
?>
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Not sure I get your need - can you not simply view the contents of the included files in the order they're included?

Comment: A quick search yielded [pp4php](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/pp4php), which looks like it might do what you need.

Comment: I am trying to debug a WordPress website, and I can not see where the heck it is accessing a table in a database.

Michael, there are files that seem to be included without the include directive.

Comment: @Shane ah, via some autoload feature somewhere probably.  Check [`debug_backtrace()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and also look into profiling the code with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org), which would allow you to see all calls in the script's execution. These won't show you the code executed exactly, but will show what functions are called and from which files.

Comment: Couldn't you link up the debugger and just step through line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// at the end of your script
<?php
$totalRunCode = '';
$scripts = get_included_files();
foreach($scripts as $script)
{
   $totalRunCode .= file_get_contents($script);
}

// do whatever with totalRunCode
```

Though I don't know why you'd want to do this.

Comment: It's not that easy. Imagine `if (false) include 'file';` code

Comment: Thanks Lusitanian, that was perfect! :)